# Is there a good way to maintain Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 versions of a project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

If you have the same libraries that are used in VS 2008 and VS 2010, is there some good tool or technique that allows you to keep both the 2008 and 2010 project files in sync?

Comment: Is VS2008 a requirement? Could you just build with VS2010 for .Net 3.5?

Comment: To expand on what Joel says, the multi-targeting support in VS 2010 is *quite* good, and not just for .NET applications. It also supports building C/C++ code using the previous versions of the compiler and SDK. If possible, I highly recommend this approach over trying to maintain two separate solution files.

Comment: yes, 2008 is a requirement.  sadly :)  Its not so much the solution files, but project files.  Libraries mainly that are incorporated across applications  ( which use different visual studios... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same project files can be loaded in both VS2008 and VS2010. If you mean solution, however, then yes, it has to be different.

What I do is just create 2 solutions:

MyProject2008.sln and MyProject2010.sln

It does mean I have to manually add projects to them once but these can be exactly the same projects files and since project structure doesn't change often in a solution it isn't a big problem in my eyes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: just as a note.   You need to convert your projects to 2010.  They will still work in a 2008 solution.